# Optimization when checking existence of more than 1 unique constraint?

Tags: mysql, optimization, unique-constraint

I am trying to optimize this query when i am checking if username or email are already taken.

More optimized because i believe one query can be created to achieve this?

```
select
(select count(Username) from User where Username = @Username) > 0 as "UsernameExist"
(select count(Email) from User where Email = @Email) > 0 as "EmailExist"
```

Query below will not work, because if username and email are for different users, i will still get count of 1

```
select count(Username), count(Email)
from User
where Username = @Username or Email = @Email
```

Comment: The second one won't work as it stands.  The first one can be slightly simplified by using `EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username = @Username ) as "UsernameExist"`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called conditional counting and you can do it using sum() or count() with a conditional statement as a parameter. I'll give you an example with sum():

```
select sum(if(Username=@Username,1,0)), sum(if(Email=@Email,1,0))
from User
where Username = @Username or Email = @Email
```

You may use a case statement instead of if() function within the sum().

However, I'm not sure if this approach is more efficient than using multiple queries. Honestly, I would use a union of the 2 queries you have as subqueries within your original query.

Comment: Well this is exactly what i need! It must be better, 2 queries are going 2 times through whole data... Thanks!
and it works good, i dont even need "where Username = @Username or Email = @Email" part

Comment: When you look into optimizing queries a bit more, you will realise that sometimes 2 simple queries complete faster than 1 complicated. Keep the where, even if the conditional counting works without it.

Comment: I believe you are right, if its how i imagine selecting behind the scenes:
(1)I think 2 queries will both check for its field if it exist, on each record, and then increment the counter for count. (2) 1 query with where will execute 1 or 2 ifs on record, than if record exist it will execute 2-4 ifs for sum part, and then will execute a sum - is this is what you mean by 'keep the where'? and is this what you thinking overall, from my analysis (1) approach is better as you said?

Comment: Roughly. Plus add index usage on the top of it. Your original version (which I would rewrite as a union to save a select) can use indexes created on email / username columns. Mysql, however, is notorious for badly optimising "or" conditions within where. Even its own documentation suggest to use union instead of "or".

Comment: Anytime! Btw, if you are realky interested in query optimisation, then start to learn how to use explain command and more importantly, how to interpret its output.

Comment: Yes i am. when i notice that there could be better option. Thanks for the explain plan... didn't know it exist!

Comment: `SUM(Username=@Username)` also works.  (no `IF`, no `CASE`)

Comment: @RickJames I prefer not to rely on implicit type conversions. Just in case they are silently changed.